# C++ Class member functions

Tags: c++, class

I am asked how many members there are in the following class:

```
class xClass { 
 private: 
 int u; 
 double w; 

 public: 
 void func(); 
 void print() const; 
 xClass();
 xClass(int a, double b); 
};
```

i only see 6, but the solution says 9?

Comment: Seems you misunderstood the question.

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_member_functions

Comment: Actually in C++11 the correct answer should be 11 since there are also the move ctor and assignment, so the question is outdated or it should state which C++ standard is taken into consideration.

Comment: to clarify what everybody is saying, there are member functions that are automatically added by the compiler e.g. destructor

Comment: The question is misleading. It should ask like, how many user defined members and how many auto generated members

Answer (score 2):

This is for C++ 11.

**§ 9.2 Class members:**

> Members of a class are data members, member functions (9.3), ...

**§ 12 Special member functions:**

> The default constructor (12.1), copy constructor and copy assignment operator (12.8), move constructor and move assignment operator (12.8), and destructor (12.4) are special member functions. [Note: The implementation will implicitly declare these member functions ...]

This hints at the fact that special member functions are indeed member functions (unlike the tasmanian tiger, which is not a tiger) and therefore class members in the sense of 9.2.

> An implicitly-declared special member function is declared at the closing } of the class-specifier.

This means, special member functions are not added to the class at a later stage (e.g. during compilation); they're there once the class has been defined. Also, special member functions are declared even if they are not used.

To summarize: in C++ 11, there are 11 members. In C++ 03, move constructor and move assignment operator do not exist, so there might be 9 members. However, I did not check the wording for C++ 03, so there might be 6 members.

Answer (score 0):

I read the comments but I have to say that it is difficult to say how many class members in your example. I think that there are some contradictions in the C++ Standard description. For example in section 9.2 Class members there is said

> 1 The member-specification in a class definition declares the full set
>   of members of the class; no member can be added elsewhere.

So if to follow the Standard in your example there are indeed only 6 members because only they take part in the member-specification.

Also according to the C++ Standard

> Members of a class are data members, member functions (9.3),...

If to look through section 9.3 then we will see that constructors, destructors and copy and move assignment operators are not mentioned there.:) They are called special member functions. But special member functions are not mentioned among member functions.

So you can say bravely that there are only 6 class members. If somebody have questions then let he ask the C++ Standard Committee.:)